# javascript prototype object this value

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I don't really get JavaScript prototyping. In the following example why is the output of tmp.foo.tt() undefined, and how do you define it?

```
function Test(){
    this.name = 'test'
}
Test.prototype.foo = {
    tt: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
    }
} 

var tmp = new Test();
tmp.foo.tt()    //why the output is undefined, and how to change it
```

Comment: You cannot. `name` belongs to the `Test` instance, not to the `Test.foo`

Comment: Now, I want to bind this to the Test instance, how to change this code

Comment: You cannot with prototypes.

Comment: @timolawl it does not

Comment: `tmp.foo.tt.call(tmp)`

Comment: @Redu there is totally no point to use the prototype then.

Comment: @zerkms Redu's comment was what I was going after. I think OP is just experimenting with prototypes.

Comment: @Jacketfan because constructor is used only for initialization . It not returns the value. If you want it return the name then you have to developed the return function after that you can call return function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around this using a getter, although you will lose some of the advantages that prototypes generally provide:

```
function Test(){
    this.name = 'test'
}
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function() {
        var that = this;
        // that is now this
        return {
            tt: function(){
                console.log(that.name);
            }
        }
    },
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
});

var tmp = new Test();
tmp.foo.tt();
```